# Swift opening browser with buttonclick

Tags: ios, swift, browser

I don't understand why this doesn't work. It really should though! i tried it earlier in the project but when i add the code to other buttons it won't load a browser window. I can't seem to figure out what the problem is. Do i have to allow the app to open other apps? here is the code

```
@IBAction func skulder(_ sender: Any) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://www.sundhed.dk/")! as URL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

Comment: it's work for me please check proper IBAction connected and if proper then clean the project and reopen it then try

Answer (score 0):

If it worked on other Buttons the 2nd line should not be the problem. I think you do not need extra permissions either.

Without knowing your skills or circumstances, did you check that your IBActions and buttons are connected correctly?